# Use Javascript regex to match Macys to Macy's

Tags: javascript

I would like to be able to use new RegExp() in JS to match words like Macys to Macy's. Can someone show me how they would achieve this please. This is used for a search feature and i would like to return results if they the user types either spelling of the macys brand.

Comment: `/Macy'?s/` would not work?

Comment: You honestly don't want to write your own search engine. What about different spellings, typos and fuzzy search? There are a lot of libraries which already do this for you.

Comment: I'd have to find the indexOf the apostrophe and add the '?' to each query. Is that what you are suggesting. Was hoping there'd be a more simple way to say find if macys or macy's

Comment: I agree with Christoph, Its a nightmare but needs to be done. Looked at Levenshtein distance which is handy for word matching but a bit over the top. Think the answer torazaburo mentioned will have to do for now.

Comment: @stu6188 check out my answer if you want an alternative...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/macy'?s/gmi
```

macy matches the characters

```
macy
```

literally (case insensitive)

```
'?
```

matches the character ' literally

Quantifier: ? Between zero and one time, as many times as possible, giving back as needed[greedy]

```
s
```

matches the character s literally (case insensitive)

g modifier:global.

Demo: 
https://regex101.com/r/tV6yG1/1

PS: I'm using the stack android app and I cannot format the code as I'd like, but you get the idea of what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

As @torazaburo pointed out: `/Macy'?s/` is the regex you want. If you want it to be case-insensitive, add the `i` flag at the end of the regex.

```
/Macy'?s/i.test('Macys'); // true
/Macy'?s/i.test("Macy's"); // true
/Macy'?s/i.test("macys"); // true
```